# Moment Generating Function Question (Simple)

Tags: probability

Define $U=-\log(Z/10)$.
$Z$ is a random variable, and $f_Z(z)=1/10$, $0\le Z \le 10$.

Moment generating function :
$M_U(t)=E[e^{-t\log(Z/10)}]=E[(Z/10)^{-t}]=\int_{0}^{10} \frac{1}{10} {(\frac{z}{10})}^{-t} dz= 
\frac{1}{1-t}$ where $t<1$.
Why $t<1$ is necessary in here?

Comment: So that you can take it's taylor series expansion to compute $r^{th}$ moment of $U$

Comment: The function $z\mapsto  z^t$ is integrable at $0$ if and only if $t>-1$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand well. Could you explain more explicitly for me?

Answer (score 2):

> Because the random variable $\mathrm e^{tU}$ is integrable if and only if $t\lt1$.

Note that $\mathrm e^U=1/V$ where $V$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ hence
$$
\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{tU})=\mathbb E(V^{-t})=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dv}{v^t},
$$
and that the integral
$$
\int_0\frac{\mathrm dv}{v^t}
$$
converges for $t\lt1$ and diverges for $t\geqslant1$.